# Update Logic for JPA Entity Fails when using DBUnit and Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, dbunit

I am currently using DBUnit in conjunction with Spring in order to unit test my application, but have run into an issue where my update logic test always fails because a deadlock occurs on the database and I cannot figure out why this is the case.  Please note that I have been able to get around the issue by removing the method annotated by @After, which really isn't needed because I am using the @TransactionConfiguration annotation, but I'm concerned that I'm misunderstanding something regarding how the transaction processing works and thus am hoping someone can indicate why I always get the following exception when running my updateTerritory method.

```
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
```

One thing that may be helpful to point out is that I am able to perform other actions like querying the database and inserting new records without any lock errors.  In addition I am using OpenJPA and spring is injecting the PersistenceUnit into my DAO.  I'm guessing that mixing up the usage of the PersistenceUnit and the direct use of the datasource within my DBUnit setup code (testSetup and testTeardown) may be part of the issue.  I'm currently using Derby as my database.

My Code is provided below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TerritoryZoneManagerTest {

@Autowired
private DataSource unitTestingDataSource;

@Autowired
private ITerritoryZoneDaoManager mgr;

@Before
public void testSetup() throws DatabaseUnitException, SQLException,
        FileNotFoundException {
    Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(unitTestingDataSource);
    IDatabaseConnection dbUnitCon = new DatabaseConnection(con);

    FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
    IDataSet dataSet = builder
            .build(new FileInputStream(
                    "./src/com.company.territoryzonelookup/dao/test/TerritoryZoneManagerTest.xml"));

    try {

        // NOTE: There is no need to use the DatabaseOperation.DELETE
        // functionality because spring will automatically remove all
        // inserted records after each test case is executed.
        DatabaseOperation.REFRESH.execute(dbUnitCon, dataSet);
    } finally {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, unitTestingDataSource);
    }
}

    @After
public void testTeardown() throws DatabaseUnitException, SQLException,
        FileNotFoundException {
    Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(unitTestingDataSource);
    IDatabaseConnection dbUnitCon = new DatabaseConnection(con);

    FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
    IDataSet dataSet = builder
            .build(new FileInputStream(
                    "./src/com.company.territoryzonelookup/dao/test/TerritoryZoneManagerTest.xml"));

    try {

        // NOTE: There is no need to use the DatabaseOperation.DELETE
        // functionality because spring will automatically remove all
        // inserted records after each test case is executed.
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE.execute(dbUnitCon, dataSet);
    } finally {
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, unitTestingDataSource);
    }
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void updateTerritory() {
    TerritoryZone zone = new TerritoryZone();
    int id = 1;
    zone = mgr.getTerritory(id);

    String newCity = "Congerville";
    zone.setCity(newCity);
    mgr.updateTerritory(zone);

    zone = mgr.getTerritory(id);
    Assert.assertEquals(newCity, zone.getCity());
}
}
```

The DAO object is provided below as well in case that is useful.

```
@Repository
public class TerritoryZoneDaoManager implements ITerritoryZoneDaoManager {

/*
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
*/

/*
 * @PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory emf;
 * 
 * @PersistenceContext private EntityManager getEntityManager(){ return
 * emf.createEntityManager(); }
 */

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    // return emf.createEntityManager();
    return em;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.ITerritoryZoneManager#addTerritory(com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.TerritoryZone)
 */
@Override
public TerritoryZone addTerritory(TerritoryZone territoryZone) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.persist(territoryZone);
    return territoryZone;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.ITerritoryZoneManager#getTerritory(int)
 */
@Override
public TerritoryZone getTerritory(int id) {
    TerritoryZone obj = null;
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("selectById");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    obj = (TerritoryZone) query.getSingleResult();
    return obj;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.ITerritoryZoneManager#updateTerritory(com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.TerritoryZone)
 */
@Override
public TerritoryZone updateTerritory(TerritoryZone territoryZone){
    getEntityManager().merge(territoryZone);
    return territoryZone;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.ITerritoryZoneManager#getActiveTerritoriesByStateZipLob(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public List<TerritoryZone> getActiveTerritoriesByStateZipLob(String stateCd, String zipCode, Date effectiveDate, String lobCd){
    List<TerritoryZone> territoryList;

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("selectActiveByZipStateLob");
    query.setParameter("zipCode", zipCode);
    query.setParameter("state", stateCd);
    query.setParameter("lob",lobCd);
    query.setParameter("effectiveDate", effectiveDate);

    territoryList = (List<TerritoryZone>) query.getResultList();

    return territoryList;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.company.territoryzonelookup.dao.ITerritoryZoneManager#deleteAll()
 */
@Override
public void deleteAll(){
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("Delete from TerritoryZone");
    query.executeUpdate();
}

/***
 * the load method will remove all existing records from the database and then will reload it using it the data passed.
 * @param terrList
 */
public void load(List<TerritoryZone> terrList){
    deleteAll();
    for (TerritoryZone terr:terrList){
        addTerritory(terr);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.
Jeremy

Comment: Why do you release connection manually in setup/teardown methods? DataSourceUtils.getConnection should give you thread-bound connection with active transaction opened by spring test framework. This connection should also be closed by the framework.

Comment: Good point @mrembisz.  I have removed the calls to DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection, but am still encountering the same issue.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest then is enabling debug logging for org.springframework.transaction/jdbc and confirm transactions and connections are accessed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

jwmajors81

i can not know what's wrong with your unit testing code for lacking some details.

i also used spring unit test and dbunit for my himvc framework, a RAD framework based on spring3 and hibernate. here is the code of my super class for unit testing，

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:config/application-test-config.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class HiMVCTransactionalUnitTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
    @Autowired
    protected DBUnitHelper dbHelper;

    protected void loadFixture(){

        try{
            String fixtureFile=this.dbHelper.getDataFile();
            if(fixtureFile==null){
                fixtureFile=this.getDefaultXMLFixtureFile();
                this.dbHelper.setDataFile(fixtureFile);
            }
            if(this.dbHelper.isDataFileExisted()){
                if(this.dbHelper.isMSSQL()){
                    HiMVCInsertIdentityOperation operation=new HiMVCInsertIdentityOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
                    operation.setInTransaction(true);
                    this.dbHelper.executeDBOperation(operation);
                }else{
                    this.dbHelper.executeDBOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception x){
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

...
}
```

i use the @Transactional annotation in the class declaration, and also specified the transactionManager. i wrote a DBUnitHelper to wrap the dbunit details of data loading.

here is a unit test sample:

```
public class MyTest extends HiMVCTransactionalUnitTest{
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        super.loadFixture();
    }
    //other testing methods
}
```

Hope these codes helpful.